# How to count total number Google Plus share of an url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have tried to count total number of Google Plus shares of an url. But unfortunately i didn't find any proper way to have this.I found the following code to have this but don't know how to use the code. What is the proper way of using the following code to have this functionalities? How to use this code?
Please check the link below

[How to use this code to count total number of google plus shares?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADqi.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADqi.png

Answer (score 0):

To get count of total shares on google+ of a url please checkout these link:
 https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302

or

http://mycodingtricks.com/php/how-to-count-google-social-share-for-a-url-using-php/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But can you tell me in details where to add those?

Answer (score 0):

I will need use ajax request by this url https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=YOUR_API_KEY, 
and replace YOUR_API_KEY -  you api-key will get from google+.

and method: get.
Then in a response you will get a something like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADqi.png

Comment: Please don't put text as an image.